# How many requests and tweets per request do I get when running this tweepy script?

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to retrieve tweets based on Hashtag name and save them as a JSON file for later analysis. I read twitter's documentations but unfortunately I didn't understand. Below is a code snippet.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=hashtag_name,count=100,wait_on_rate_limit=True ,wait_on_rate_limit_notify= True).items():
    # Create and save the data on the Desktop as a JSON file.
    f= open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")+'/'+time_str+'/'+'%d_%s_tweets.json'%(file_name_counter,hashtag_category), 'a',encoding="utf-8") 
    f.write(json.dumps(tweet._json))
    f.write("\n")
    file_name_counter += 1
```

I want to know:

- How many requests does this code sends per minute?
- How much tweets does 1 request retrieves?
- Where exactly does this code send a request to twitter server? 
  Eventually I want to save each request's tweets on a JSON file

Comment: Can you please tell me why did you down-vote my question?
if I'm doing something wrong I would like to know what it is and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many requests does this code sends per minute?

This code loops without any sleep, so it sends as much as requests it can. And it's a bad idea because of rate limits.

> How much tweets does 1 request retrieves?

Your parameter is `count=100` so the answser is 100.

> Where exactly does this code send a request to twitter server?

It goes to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json

> Eventually I want to save each request's tweets on a JSON file

It is actually doing this.

Please read : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html